# LocalStorage not properly work in Iframes (SAFARI browser)

Tags: javascript, macos, iframe, safari, local-storage

When i'm try to use the LocalStorage in Iframes , it not work fine (**occasionally works fine**)

> Browser(**SAFARI**) not able identify the domains . so, it create false
>   instance of LocalStorage for same Domain

Example case (*tab has an iframe  of same domain*):

```
tab1   - localStorage has some values

tab2 - localStorage is Empty
```

**Note : works fine in Other browsers**

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: If you refresh tab2 is it still empty? I came across this post that might be helpful. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584126/accessing-localstorage-of-an-iframe-in-an-event-callback

Comment: while refreshing, sometime it work but many time it doesn't